# featuretools basic aggegration on time measures

Tags: feature-extraction, feature-engineering, featuretools

I am using featuretools (1.1x version), I read the docs,and also searched here

but still struggle to find how to do simple things like SELECT MIN(datetime_field_1)..

I also checked list_primitives() those related to time seem not what I need,

I can do this for numeric fields, but seems can't do it on Datetime fields..

> 

https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/

I simply want to get min(timestamp), max(timestamp) group by customer_id, but max/min primitive only works on numeric

```
import featuretools as ft
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make some random data
n = 100
events_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id" : range(n),
    "customer_id": np.random.choice(["a", "b", "c"], n),
    "timestamp": pd.date_range("Jan 1, 2019", freq="1h", periods=n),
    "amount": np.random.rand(n) * 100 
})

def to_part_of_day(x):
    if x < 12:
        return "morning"
    elif x < 18:
        return "afternoon"
    else:
        return "evening"
es = ft.EntitySet(id='my_set')
es = es.add_dataframe(dataframe = events_df, dataframe_name = 'events', time_index='timestamp', index='index')
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
  entityset=es,
  target_dataframe_name='events',
  agg_primitives=['min','max'],
  trans_primitive=[],
  primitive_options={
  'max':{
        "include_groupby_columns":{"events":["customer_id"]}
        }
  }

)
```

How should I get max(amount), max(timestamp) by each customer_id? Thanks! Feels silly to ask such basic thing after reading featuretools.alteryx.com and their github examples..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a few issues here. First of all, the `Max` and `Min` primitives only operate on numeric columns, as you mention. If your data is sorted based on the datetime value, you could use the `First` and `Last` aggregation primitives to get the first and last values, respectively, which will correspond to `Min` and `Max` if sorted in ascending order. If these primitives aren't sufficient, you will need to [define your own custom primitive](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/getting_started/primitives.html#Defining-Custom-Primitives).

Second, by default, Featuretools will not return datetime values as features. In order to get those values returned, you will need to change the `return_types` in your call to DFS to include datetime values.

Finally, your example above only uses a single dataframe in the `EntitySet`. Featuretools aggregations are only applied when multiple dataframes are present in an EntitySet. Aggregations are performed across the defined relationship. To define features for a customer you would target the customer table and then aggregate values from other tables (like purchases for example) to get features like `MAX(purchases.amount)` or `FIRST(purchases.date)`.

Here is a complete example building off your starting data:

```py
import featuretools as ft
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make some random data
n = 100
purchases_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id" : range(n),
    "customer_id": np.random.choice(["a", "b", "c"], n),
    "date": pd.date_range("Jan 1, 2019", freq="1h", periods=n),
    "amount": np.random.rand(n) * 100 
})

customers_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": ["a", "b", "c"],
})

es = ft.EntitySet()
es = es.add_dataframe(dataframe=purchases_df, dataframe_name="purchases", time_index="date", index="id")
es = es.add_dataframe(dataframe=customers_df, dataframe_name="customers", index="id")
es.add_relationship("customers", "id", "purchases", "customer_id")

feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
  entityset=es,
  target_dataframe_name='customers',
  agg_primitives=["min", "max", "first", "last"],
  trans_primitives=["month"],
  return_types="all")
```

```
    FIRST(purchases.amount) FIRST(purchases.date)  FIRST(purchases.id)  LAST(purchases.amount) LAST(purchases.date)  ...  MIN(purchases.amount)  FIRST(purchases.MONTH(date))  LAST(purchases.MONTH(date)) MONTH(FIRST(purchases.date)) MONTH(LAST(purchases.date))
id                                                                                                                   ...
a                 10.858168   2019-01-01 01:00:00                    1               77.302337  2019-01-05 03:00:00  ...               2.639971                             1                            1                            1                           1
b                 43.035418   2019-01-01 03:00:00                    3               63.446195  2019-01-04 23:00:00  ...               3.790079                             1                            1                            1                           1
c                 29.234700   2019-01-01 00:00:00                    0               78.434346  2019-01-05 01:00:00  ...               1.088463                             1                            1                            1                           1
```

If you want to return only certain column types you can pass a list of types to `return_types` instead of `"all"`. Also, if you only want `First` and `Last` to apply to the datetime column you can do that by passing appropriate values to `primitive_options` in the call to DFS. The [documentation](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/guides/specifying_primitive_options.html#Specifying-Columns-for-Individual-Primitives) contains information on how to do that.